# Jquery select closest weekdays from selected date

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I need assistance/guidance on 2 things.  First, I need to know how to grey out days from a jquery datepicker and only return Monday thru Friday Days.

I have a simple HTML form that requires the selection of date. I would like to allow selections of one date.  When the user enters any single date(Monday to Friday of whatever week in calendar), I would like to return the rest of the days in that week.

Comment: Please post the HTML and jQuery you've tried.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484479/jquery-ui-datepicker-allow-only-certain-weekdays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function can be used to enable/disable certain dates.

```
beforeShowDay: function(dt){
    var day = dt.getDay();
    var isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);
    return [!isWeekend];
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKqJH/)

Comment: How can I return a range of dates in the selected day? Example: If I select April 15, 2013, I would like to return the selected date and April 16, 2013, April 17, 2013, April 18, 2013, and April 19.

Comment: Same thing if I select April 17, 2013, I would like to return:April 15, 2013, April 16, 2013, April 17, 2013, April 18, 2013, and April 19.

Comment: You can use the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) function and then do math to calculate Monday and Friday based on the current day. I went ahead and [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKqJH/7/) with an example. Hopefully you can figure out where I'm going with it and suit it to your needs.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you idor_brad. Just what I needed!

Comment: I realized there was a bug if you pick a different month than the current month so I fixed up the fiddle to calculate the dates a little more intuitively. Sorry about that! http://jsfiddle.net/SKqJH/11/